# If, Else If, Else + ... more conditions?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using the code below (it works as described) to check if online image CDN servers are returning a cached image, then display it if true. Based on my personal preference, I display the Weserv image, and if this doesn't exist (404, 403, etc), then display the Aratech img, and finally show the original img src if Aratech fails.

My question is, how to add more IF/ELSE IF statements?

What I want is to add 2 more images CDN links, so the script will test and display the first one working (200). But from my (poor PHP) knowledge, there can be only 3: IF, ELSE IF, and ELSE.

If not possible, is there any other way to accomplish what I want? I hope my explanation is easy to understand.

```
<?php
// $thumbnail['url'] = the original img url
$weserv = rtrim(preg_replace ('/https:\/\/|http:\/\//','https://images.weserv.nl/?w=100&output=webp&url=',$thumbnail['url'],1),'/');
$header_weserv = @get_headers($weserv);

$aratech = rtrim(preg_replace ('/https:\/\/|http:\/\//','https://imagex.aratech.co/?w=100&q=75&il&output=webp&url=',$thumbnail['url'],1),'/');
$header_aratech = get_headers($aratech);

if ($header_weserv && strpos( $header_weserv[0], "200" ))
{
// 1st option
  echo $weserv; //if Weserv link returns 200 code, this will display
} 
elseif  ($header_aratech &&  strpos( $header_aratech[0], "200" ))
{
//2nd option
  echo $aratech; //if Weserv above fails and Aratech link returns 200 code, this will display instead
}
//need 3rd and 4th options before the 'else' below
else
{
  echo $thumbnail['url']; //finally, both Weserv and Aratech failed and the original link shows
}
?>
```

Comment: `if`...unlimited `else if`...`else`

Comment: You should be using a  [Switch Statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) if you have a ton of `else if`s

Comment: @j08691 I thought there can be more than 1 IF. I do want only one echo to be displayed, not all IF statements that return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add more if/elseif statements to your code. In fact, you can add as many if/elseif statements as you need to test multiple conditions.

```php
if ($header_weserv && strpos($header_weserv[0], "200")) {
  echo $weserv;
} elseif ($header_aratech && strpos($header_aratech[0], "200")) {
  echo $aratech;
} elseif ($header_cdn1 && strpos($header_cdn1[0], "200")) {
  echo $cdn1;
} elseif ($header_cdn2 && strpos($header_cdn2[0], "200")) {
  echo $cdn2;
} else {
  echo $thumbnail['url'];
}
```

You can also use a `switch` statement instead of multiple if/elseif statements :

```php
switch (true) {
  case ($header_weserv && strpos($header_weserv[0], "200")):
    echo $weserv;
    break;
  case ($header_aratech && strpos($header_aratech[0], "200")):
    echo $aratech;
    break;
  case ($header_cdn1 && strpos($header_cdn1[0], "200")):
    echo $cdn1;
    break;
  case ($header_cdn2 && strpos($header_cdn2[0], "200")):
    echo $cdn2;
    break;
  default:
    echo $thumbnail['url'];
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid, not even trying it first. I've always thought the there can be only if/else if/else :)